# pass request.user.id from view to form does not work :(

Tags: django, django-admin

views.py

```
def RealStateView(request):
    form = RealStateForm(request.user)
```

forms.py

```
class RealStateForm(forms.ModelForm):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    request = kwargs.pop('request')
    super(RealStateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['user_id'].initial = request.user.id


class Meta:
    model = RealState
    exclude = ["owner"]
    fields = '__all__'

def clean_acquisition_value(self):
    message = self.cleaned_data['acquisition_value']

    if message < 10:
        raise ValidationError('No puede ser cero')
    return message
```

the error says:

```
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value: 'request'
```

I've tried other ways without success results.. Any idea?

Comment: What is your form code?

Comment: class RealStateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = kwargs.pop('request')
        super(RealStateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user_id'].initial = request.user.id


    class Meta:
        model = RealState
        exclude = ["owner"]
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean_acquisition_value(self):
        message = self.cleaned_data['acquisition_value']

        if message < 10:
            raise ValidationError('No puede ser cero')
        return message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't passing a keyword argument called "request" to the constructor. Instead, you are passing a positional argument with the value of `request.user`.

```
form = RealStateForm(request=request)
```